# Windows 10 start menu - official apps showing as blank buttons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, windows-store-app

Like many others I've run into the "taskbar stops working" issue.
And, while that issue is still not fixed, during an attempt to fix the problem - more stuff got broken.

I've run the following command in powershell as administrator: (Since many suggested that would fix it, it did not.)

> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}

Which resulted in windows downloading/updating some stuff, giving a few errors but on overall seeming to work - but most of all, it killed a number of my apps.

Specifically: windows store, calculator and more. See:

[image: http://imgur.com/5pEnP4R]

They're just showing up as blank panels now.

Windows can no longer automatically update the "broken" apps anymore either :

[image: http://imgur.com/JugSrlx] 
(See the warning about calculator in the bottom)

I'm a bit at a loss of things to try. I've updated windows with the latest fixes available this week, so far as it was able.

How can I remove the broken apps, and/or ensure they get reinstalled properly? (Without doing a full windows reinstall, and having to reinstall visual studio, office, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Those powershell commands only work for Windows 10 Build 10240 (July 2015 Version). In Version 1511 they corrupt the Store Apps. The only known way is to [repair Windows via Inplace Upgrade](https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/#Repair_Installing_Windows_10).

- [Download the Win10 1511 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench)
- mount the ISO, run setup.exe from the virtual DVD drive
- select Upgrade and keep all files

[image]